# How to split Java list efficiently based on index passed dynamically

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Java list, I need to split the list based on the index values passed from a property file.

Example :

```
ArrayList<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
sampleList.add("1");
sampleList.add("2");
sampleList.add("3");
sampleList.add("4");
sampleList.add("5");
sampleList.add("6");
sampleList.add("7");
sampleList.add("8");
sampleList.add("9");
sampleList.add("10");
```

Let's say for the first time, the index passed from property file are 3,5. So my output should be

For example :

```
System.out.println(sampleList.subList(0,3)+" "+sampleList.get(3)+" "+sampleList.subList(4,5)+" "+sampleList.get(5)+" "+sampleList.subList(6,sampleList.size()));
```

> [1,2,3] 4 [5] 6 [7,8,9,10]

Next time if the indexes passed are 3,5,8 and the output should be

> [1,2,3] 4 [5] 6 [7,8] 9 [10]

I have tried to sublist the list and pass on the indexes manually. It does gives output but it's not efficient.

Please advice how this can be done dynamically.TIA

Comment: It's unclear to me how the given indices correspond to the expected output. Also what exactly does "no efficient" mean? Sublist should be rather fast as it doesn't copy anything.

Comment: Please show the actual code you have tried and explain how it is not efficient

Comment: Can you please explain how a split 3,5 and 3,5,8 result in the respective outputs?

Comment: Please find the sysout command I have added . This is how I m trying to split the list manually to get the result

Comment: Your example does not give you the output that you said. It outputs this: `[1, 2, 3] 4 [5] 6 [7, 8, 9, 10]` . Can you describe in words what the parameters 3 and 5 should do?

Comment: Basically 3 and 5 are the indexes. Based on his index the list has to be split into multiple sublist . Sublist one should have values of the indexes 0,1,2. Sublist two should have the value of index 3 . Sublist three should have values between the index 3 and 5 ie the value of index 4 . Sublist four should have value of the index 5 and the sublist five should have the vales from index 6 to end of the main list

Comment: @Janthegun : the output u have shown in the comment is the correct one. I have edited the question

Answer (score 3):

Made a simple solution, indexes are stored in the array, and list is not truly 'split' - I've used a subList, which is only a view. But it shows an idea:

```
    int[] indexes = {3, 5, 8};

    List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    sampleList.add("1");
    sampleList.add("2");
    sampleList.add("3");
    sampleList.add("4");
    sampleList.add("5");
    sampleList.add("6");
    sampleList.add("7");
    sampleList.add("8");
    sampleList.add("9");
    sampleList.add("10");        

    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    int lastIdx = 0;
    for (int idx: indexes) {
        if (lastIdx < idx) {
            //then this subList is not empty
            result.add(sampleList.subList(lastIdx, idx));            
        }
        //adding 'idx' element anyway
        result.add(sampleList.subList(idx, idx + 1));
        lastIdx = idx + 1;
    }
    result.add(sampleList.subList(lastIdx, sampleList.size()));

    System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4], [5], [6], [7, 8], [9], [10]]
```